# How to inject repository in .net core 3.1 background service?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In asp.net core 3.1 web application I have an event listener inherited from BackgroundService class.
Why injectiong repository which has injected DbContext makes error?

**Startup:**

```
    services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options => {
        options.UseSqlServer("...connection string...");
    });

    services.AddTransient<ICalStatRepo, CalStatRepo>();
    services.AddTransient<IHostedService, BackgroundListener>();
```

**Repository:**

```
public class CalStatRepo : ICalStatRepo
{
    private readonly DBContext _context;

    public CalStatRepo(DBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task InsertCallStat(RawCallStatRegisterViewModel model)
    {
        var rawCall = new RawCallStat
        {
            HappenedAt = model.HappenedAt,
            Source = model.Source,
            Destination = model.Destination,
            Status = model.Status
        };

        _context.Entry(rawCall).State = EntityState.Added;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Insert new call stat fails with this error : " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Background Service :**

```
public class BackgroundListener : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _service;

    public BackgroundListener(IServiceProvider service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
}
// what I want to do is insert logs into db here
private async void EvenetListener(Object sender, Event e)
{
    var calStatRepo = _service.GetRequiredService<ICalStatRepo>(); //> Error

    await calStatRepo.InsertCallStat(args);
}
```

The problem is adding required service in event listener will make an error as below:

> Cannot resolve 'Repositories.ICalStatRepo' from root provider because
>   it requires scoped service 'Models.Context.DBContext'.

DBContext has added in startup as services.AddDbContext and injected in CalStatRepo and then added as required service in event listener in background service, but why it is required as scoped service again?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AddDbContext` registers the `DbContext` as a scoped service. So you can only resolve that service within a scope.

So you only have to create a scope and dispose it when not needed any longer:

```
public class BackgroundListener : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _service;

    public BackgroundListener(IServiceProvider service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    // what I want to do is insert logs into db here
    private async void EvenetListener(Object sender, Event e)
    {
        using ( var scope = _service.CreateScope() )
        {
            var calStatRepo = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICalStatRepo>();
            await calStatRepo.InsertCallStat(args);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default background services do not have scope created. To resolve scoped services such as `DbContext`, you need to create a child scope off the root container.

Have a look at [how to use scoped services in background services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task).