# DbContext in Service triggered by Hangfire

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I have a .NET 6 Razor Pages app that triggers background tasks and then informs the user of their status via SignalR.

I'm trying to use Database1 context in the PerformBackgroundJob method, but it's disposed. What technique should I use to inject Database1 context in PerformBackgroundJob, or how else can I get this to work?

```
namespace Toolkat.Pages
{
    public class ProcessModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly Database1Context _context;
        private readonly ToolkatContext _tkcontext;
        private IConfiguration configuration;
        private readonly IQueue _queue;
        private readonly IHubContext<JobHub> _hubContext;

        static ServerConnection conn;
        static Server server;
        static Job job;

        public ProcessModel(
            Database1Context context,
            ToolkatContext tkcontext,
            IConfiguration _configuration,
            IQueue queue,
            IHubContext<JobHub> hubContext)
        {
            _context = context;
            _tkcontext = tkcontext;
            configuration = _configuration;
            _queue = queue;
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        public IList<CustomFileImport> CustomFileImport { get; set; } = default!;

        [BindProperty]
        public CustomFileImport CustomFileImportNumberTwo { get; set; } = default!;



        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            if (_context.CustomFileImports != null)
            {
                CustomFileImport = await _context.CustomFileImports
                .Include(c => c.FileImportType)
                .Include(c => c.FileImportStatus)
                .Where(i => i.FileImportStatusId.Equals(1))
                .ToListAsync();
            }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int[] fileImportId)
        {
            //Generate GUID
            Guid jobId = Guid.NewGuid();

            //Update FileImportItems with GUID
            foreach (var id in fileImportId)
            {

                if (/*id == null ||*/ _context.CustomFileImports == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                var customfileimport = await _context.CustomFileImports.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.FileImportId == id);
                if (customfileimport == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                customfileimport.ProcessId = jobId;

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            }


            _queue.QueueAsyncTask(() => PerformBackgroundJob(jobId));


            return RedirectToPage("./Result", new { jobId });
        }


        private async Task PerformBackgroundJob(Guid jobId /*CancellationToken cancellationToken*/)
        {

            await _hubContext.Clients.Group(jobId.ToString()).SendAsync("progress", "PerformBackgroundJob Started");

            /*
            var customFileImports = await _context.CustomFileImports
                .Include(c => c.FileImportType)
                .Where(i => i.ProcessId.Equals(jobId))
                .ToListAsync();
            */

            Debug.WriteLine("ProviderName:" + _context.Database.ProviderName);

            /*
            foreach (var f in customFileImports)
            {
                await _hubContext.Clients.Group(jobId.ToString()).SendAsync("progress", WebUtility.HtmlEncode(f.FileName));
            }
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to inject repository in .net core 3.1 background service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61303699/how-to-inject-repository-in-net-core-3-1-background-service)

Comment: I looked into that but it doesn't appear to answer my question because in my example I am using Coravel as the task queue, not my own background service. My question is how can I utilize a DB context in the method PerformBackgrounJob.

Comment: You need to retrieve context from `scope.ServiceProvider`, as shown in answer. Context should be created in Scope and after disposing Scope it will Disposed also. You should not inject context for background service via constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your help, can you please illustrate your suggestion via my example code, that will help me better understand. And to clarify, I didn't even write a class that inherits BackGroundService, in this example I am using Coravel instead of writing my own background service. That's why I can't figure out how that article solves my issue.

Comment: You should `await` in `OnGetAsync()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to combine lessons from lots of articles to figure this out. Hangfire has a nice way of approaching this.

Replace

```cs
_queue.QueueAsyncTask(() => PerformBackgroundJob(jobId));
```

With

```cs
BackgroundJob.Enqueue<ProcessFilesService>(x => x.DoWork());
```

[Passing dependencies](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/passing-dependencies.html)

and create this class

```cs
public class ProcessFilesService
{
    IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public ProcessFilesService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

        public void DoWork()
        {
            using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            var ctx = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDatabaseContext>();

            using var hubScope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            var _hubContext = hubScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<JobHub>();

            Debug.WriteLine(ctx.Database.ProviderName);
        }
}
```

Hmm...I didn't need to register it as a service in program.cs and it appears to still be working. Will have to learn more about that.

Comment: `using (MyDatabaseContext ctx` is not needed, if context registered as Scoped it will be disposed with Scope automatically.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, can you advise on how to correct the code with a code example?

Comment: Corrected your answer.

Comment: Thanks a million, can you also demonstrate how to inject a JobHubContext in this service as well, I would be glad to accept that as the answer instead of mine.

Comment: I gave it shot, let me know if you see any issues.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv "using (IServiceScope scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope()) { ... }" is actually needed to as there is no manuall call to scope.Dispose() so the current version of the answer would not dispose the database context. See the following link where a microsoft employee is mentioning that https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23460#issuecomment-651758324. Also take a look at the comment just above.

Comment: @Christian, probably you have missed new C# syntax `using var scope`.