# LINQ query does not fetch all data ...sometimes

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In a super, duper ASP.NET Core 3.1/Sql Server/EF Core web application, a LINQ query is used to fetch all reminders for recurring medical tests that pet owners should be notified about:

```
_context.Tests
.Where(t => t.Visit.User.SMSAccount != null
       && t.Visit.User.SMSAccount.AutoReminder
       && t.Visit.Customer.Consent
       && (t.Visit.Customer.ContactBy == "Mobile")
       && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Visit.Customer.Mobile)
       && !t.Visit.Pet.PassedAway
       && t.Reminder.HasValue
       && !t.ReminderSMSSent
       && DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(t.Visit.User.SMSAccount.DaysBefore.Value) == t.Reminder)
.Include(t => t.Visit.User.SMSAccount)
.Include(t => t.Visit.Customer)
.Include(t => t.Visit.Pet)
.AsNoTracking();
```

The job is done in a `BackgroundService` which run every day at noon. Pet owners are notified `DaysBefore` days before the actual reminder date. For example, if a pet is to be re-vaccinated at 2024-01-01 and `DaysBefore` is set to 7, the service will send a SMS notification at 2023-12-25.

While the service run nicely, the query sometimes does not fetch all data. I've run out of ideas why and thought a helping hand could be of use. One glitch I can spot as I am writing this is that `t.Reminder` date field is also nullable and I should probably have written `t.Reminder.Value`. Other than that I don't understand why the query fetches e.g. 3 rows out of 4 while all 4 rows in the database meet the conditions. I've run SQL queries and even debugged the service with specific dates (to simulate normal execution) and the rows that were originally omitted do show up (those rows still have the `ReminderSMSSent` to false so they still meet all conditions; that bit field becomes 1 when the notification is sent).

I know the query is a huge one -it literally looks into thousands of rows and joins many tables; the workflow is as follows:

**Background service**

```
public class SmsSenderService : BackgroundService
{
  protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
  {
    do
    {  
      // wait until it's noon                
      int timeToWait = 12 - DateTime.Now.Hour;

      // DateTime.Now.Hour is in 24h. 
      int numberOfHours = (timeToWait < 0) ? 24 - Math.Abs(timeToWait) : timeToWait;

      if (timeToWait == 0)
      {
        using var scope = this.serviceProvider.CreateScope();

        var testService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TestService>();
        var reminders = await testService.GetSmsRemindersAsync();

        var smsService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SmsService>();
        var results = smsService.SendSms(reminders.Reminders);

        // log each result...

        numberOfHours = 24;
      }

      await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(numberOfHours), stoppingToken);            
    }
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested);       
  }  
}
```

**TestService.GetSmsRemindersAsync**

```
public async Task<GetSmsRemindersResponse> GetSmsRemindersAsync()
{
    GetSmsRemindersResponse response = new GetSmsRemindersResponse();

    var results = await this.testRepository.GetSmsReminders().ToListAsync();

    response.Reminders = results.ConvertToReminderSmsList();

    return response;
}
```

**TestRepository.GetSmsReminders**

```
public IQueryable<Test> GetSmsReminders()
{
    return _context.Tests
    .Where(t => t.Visit.User.SMSAccount != null && 
            t.Visit.User.SMSAccount.AutoReminder &&
            t.Visit.Customer.Consent &&
            (t.Visit.Customer.ContactBy == "Mobile") &&
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Visit.Customer.Mobile) &&
            !t.Visit.Pet.PassedAway &&
            t.Reminder.HasValue && 
            !t.ReminderSMSSent &&
            DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(t.Visit.User.SMSAccount.DaysBefore.Value) == t.Reminder)
    .Include(t => t.Visit.User.SMSAccount)
    .Include(t => t.Visit.Customer)
    .Include(t => t.Visit.Pet)
    .AsNoTracking();
}
```

I've run the query using LinqPad with `DateTime.Now` replaced with `new DateTime(2023,10,22)` to emulate the real scenario. Here's the equivalent SQL:

```
-- Region Parameters
-- @__dt_Date_0='2023-10-22T00:00:00'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[Comments], [t].[LimitSet], [t].[Reminder], [t].[ReminderCustomerNotified], [t].[ReminderSMSSent], [t].[Results], [t].[Stamp], [t].[Status], [t].[Type], [t].[VisitId]
FROM [Tests] AS [t]
INNER JOIN [Visits] AS [v] ON [t].[VisitId] = [v].[Id]
INNER JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [a] ON [v].[UserId] = [a].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Customers] AS [c] ON [v].[CustomerId] = [c].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Pets] AS [p] ON [v].[PetId] = [p].[Id]
WHERE ((((((((
    SELECT TOP(1) [s].[AutoReminder]
    FROM [SMSAccounts] AS [s]
    WHERE [a].[Id] = [s].[UserId]) = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND ([c].[Consent] = CAST(1 AS bit))) AND (([c].[ContactBy] = N'Τηλέφωνο κινητό') OR ([c].[ContactBy] = N'Email και Κινητό'))) AND [c].[Mobile] IS NOT NULL) AND ([p].[PassedAway] <> CAST(1 AS bit))) AND [t].[Reminder] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t].[ReminderSMSSent] <> CAST(1 AS bit))) AND ((DATEADD(day, CAST(CAST((
    SELECT TOP(1) [s0].[DaysBefore]
    FROM [SMSAccounts] AS [s0]
    WHERE [a].[Id] = [s0].[UserId]) AS float) AS int), @__dt_Date_0) = [t].[Reminder]) OR (DATEADD(day, CAST(CAST((
    SELECT TOP(1) [s0].[DaysBefore]
    FROM [SMSAccounts] AS [s0]
    WHERE [a].[Id] = [s0].[UserId]) AS float) AS int), @__dt_Date_0) IS NULL AND [t].[Reminder] IS NULL))
```

It seems there's little to do to solve the problem. Maybe I should change the question; How would you implement this functionality so it runs consistently?

**LAST UPDATE:** Unfortunately, it seems this is one of those questions that just cannot be resolved. I've decided to ask [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77880763/how-safe-is-to-call-linq-ef-core-queries-in-backgroundservice-of-asp-net-core-we) about background services and linq queries hosted in a asp.net core web application. Thanks everyone for your comments.

Comment: The use of `DateTime.Now` is fragile and not a good way to identify instants. Are you sure all the components involved in the process (DB, web server...) are on the same time zone?

Comment: How background service is instantiated? `DbContext` should be recreated on each background request and disposed right away. If `ExecuteAsync` executed simultaneously on the same context you will have multi-threading issue.

Comment: I would suggest to check with [SQL Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16) & verify the query generated by `EF`, try to identify any issue with generated query and do necessary updates in `linq`.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Hmm, there is the following line in Startup.cs: `services.AddHostedService<SmsSenderService>();`. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @vc74 Yes, time zone is the same.

Comment: Also, you may check if `t.Reminder` has type `date` or `datetime`. If it is `datetime` then verify that your missing rows may have some timestamp value in `t.Reminder`.

Comment: Nice answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61303801/10646316). Idea is to store  `IServiceProvider` not `DBContext` and `CreateScope` for each request. From scope you can retrieve `DbContext` which will be disposed automatically when disposed it's scope.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I've updated the code to demonstrate that I am following exactly that methodology. `IServiceProvider` is passed as an argument to the constructor of the background service.

Comment: @dpant, well? Does issue still exists?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes. What I meant is that I updated the sample code of the question -not the actual code. I am already using `IServiceProvider`. Also, all dates do not include time i.e. they all look like `2023-11-02 00:00:00.0000000`. @Karan I am running the query using LinqPad 8. I will update the question with the equivalent SQL.

Comment: @GertArnold I've updated the original post accordingly.

Comment: Have you noticed that your query says `AND ([t].[ReminderSMSSent] = CAST(1 AS bit))` when the code asks for `!t.ReminderSMSSent`?

Comment: @MateusZampol Sorry about that. Pasted the wrong sample. It's been fixed.

Comment: complete guess based on reading the code. Try to rewrite with Include and ThenInclude

Comment: @ThomasKoelle can you please explain why I should try that?