# How safe is to call LINQ EF Core queries in BackgroundService of ASP.NET Core web application?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

*NOTE: This question is related to [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77839267/linq-query-does-not-fetch-all-data-sometimes).  I felt I should ask a new question instead of modifying the old one with respect to the user comments, which unfortunately didn't resolve it. Nevertheless, this is an autonomous question and not a duplicate.*

In a super, duper ASP.NET Core, SQL Server, EF Core web application, a LINQ query is used to fetch all reminders for recurring medical tests that customers should be notified about:

```
_context.Tests
.Where(t => t.Visit.User.SMSAccount != null
       && t.Visit.User.SMSAccount.AutoReminder
       && t.Visit.Customer.Consent
       && (t.Visit.Customer.ContactBy == "Τηλέφωνο κινητό" || t.Visit.Customer.ContactBy == "Email και Κινητό")
       && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Visit.Customer.Mobile)
       && !t.Visit.Pet.PassedAway
       && t.Reminder.HasValue
       && !t.ReminderSMSSent
       && DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(t.Visit.User.SMSAccount.DaysBefore.Value) == t.Reminder)
.Include(t => t.Visit.User.SMSAccount)
.Include(t => t.Visit.Customer)
.Include(t => t.Visit.Pet)
.AsNoTracking();
```

The job is done in a `BackgroundService` which runs every day at noon. Customers are notified `DaysBefore` days before the actual reminder date. For example, for a reminder at 2024-01-01, the service sends the notification at 2023-12-25 if the user has set `DaysBefore` to 7.

The `BackgroundService` is run as part of the ASP.NET Core Web Application, which is hosted in IIS on Windows Server 2012 R2. It uses a scoped service, which in turn issues the above LINQ query (`testService.GetSmsRemindersAsync`):

```
public class SmsSenderService : BackgroundService
{
  public SmsSenderService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
  {
    this.logger = logger;
    this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
  }

  protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
  {
    do
    {  
      // ... wait until it's noon                
      if (timeToWait == 0)
      {
        using var scope = this.serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var testService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TestService>();
        var reminders = await testService.GetSmsRemindersAsync();

        numberOfHours = 24;  // time to wait until next execution
      }

      await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(numberOfHours), stoppingToken);            
    }
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested);       
  }  
}
```

In `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs` the background service is added to the `IServiceCollection`:

```
services.AddHostedService<SmsSenderService>();
```

First, does anyone know if this is a good way to perform a task that affects all users of the application regardless of which user is currently logged in?

Also, does anyone know exactly when the background service is invoked on the web server? Is it possible that the service won't run under certain circumstances e.g. the IIS process is idle etc.?

Second, is it possible that the above design affects the behavior of the LINQ query? I have noticed that not all data are returned from time to time. I cannot find out why this happens. I 've tried to simulate the whole process using LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var dt = new DateTime(2024,1,24);
    
    var data = Tests
    .Where(t => t.Visit.User.UserSMSAccounts != null 
            && t.Visit.User.UserSMSAccounts.FirstOrDefault().AutoReminder
            && t.Visit.Customer.Consent
            && (t.Visit.Customer.ContactBy == "Τηλέφωνο κινητό" || t.Visit.Customer.ContactBy == "Email και Κινητό")
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Visit.Customer.Mobile)
            && !t.Visit.Pet.PassedAway
            && t.Reminder.HasValue
            && !t.ReminderSMSSent 
            && dt.Date.AddDays(t.Visit.User.UserSMSAccounts.FirstOrDefault().DaysBefore.Value) == t.Reminder.Value);    
    
    var results = ConvertToReminderSmsList(data);   
    results.Dump();
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here

IEnumerable<ReminderSms> ConvertToReminderSmsList(IEnumerable<Tests> tests)
{
    List<ReminderSms> reminderSmsList = new List<ReminderSms>();
    foreach (Tests test in tests)
    {
        reminderSmsList.Add(ConvertToReminderSms(test));
    }
    return reminderSmsList;
}

ReminderSms ConvertToReminderSms(Tests test)
{
    var reminderSms = new ReminderSms
    {
        Id = test.Id,
        ApiKey = test.Visit.User.UserSMSAccounts.FirstOrDefault().APIKEY,
        SmsType = test.Visit.User.UserSMSAccounts.FirstOrDefault().SMSType,
        Sender = test.Visit.User.UserSMSAccounts.FirstOrDefault().Sender,
        Recipient = test.Visit.Customer.Mobile
    };

    StringBuilder smsMessage = new StringBuilder();
    smsMessage.Append(test.Visit.User.UserSMSAccounts.FirstOrDefault().Message);
    reminderSms.Message = smsMessage.ToString();
    return reminderSms;
}

class ReminderSms
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Sender { get; set; }

    public string Recipient { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public string ApiKey { get; set; }

    public string SmsType { get; set; }
}
```

The above code works as expected and all data are returned and processed. The SQL that corresponds to the LINQ query is the following:

```
-- Region Parameters
-- @__dt_Date_0='2023-10-22T00:00:00'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[Comments], [t].[LimitSet], [t].[Reminder], [t].[ReminderCustomerNotified], [t].[ReminderSMSSent], [t].[Results], [t].[Stamp], [t].[Status], [t].[Type], [t].[VisitId]
FROM [Tests] AS [t]
INNER JOIN [Visits] AS [v] ON [t].[VisitId] = [v].[Id]
INNER JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [a] ON [v].[UserId] = [a].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Customers] AS [c] ON [v].[CustomerId] = [c].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [Pets] AS [p] ON [v].[PetId] = [p].[Id]
WHERE ((((((((
    SELECT TOP(1) [s].[AutoReminder]
    FROM [SMSAccounts] AS [s]
    WHERE [a].[Id] = [s].[UserId]) = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND ([c].[Consent] = CAST(1 AS bit))) AND (([c].[ContactBy] = N'Τηλέφωνο κινητό') OR ([c].[ContactBy] = N'Email και Κινητό'))) AND [c].[Mobile] IS NOT NULL) AND ([p].[PassedAway] <> CAST(1 AS bit))) AND [t].[Reminder] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t].[ReminderSMSSent] <> CAST(1 AS bit))) AND ((DATEADD(day, CAST(CAST((
    SELECT TOP(1) [s0].[DaysBefore]
    FROM [SMSAccounts] AS [s0]
    WHERE [a].[Id] = [s0].[UserId]) AS float) AS int), @__dt_Date_0) = [t].[Reminder]) OR (DATEADD(day, CAST(CAST((
    SELECT TOP(1) [s0].[DaysBefore]
    FROM [SMSAccounts] AS [s0]
    WHERE [a].[Id] = [s0].[UserId]) AS float) AS int), @__dt_Date_0) IS NULL AND [t].[Reminder] IS NULL))
```

But when deployed on the web server some data are just missing occasionally. Can anyone think of any good reason?

UPDATE: the background service uses the application's DbContext, which is configured in `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
    Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"),
    sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(90))
);
```

Constructor DI is used to pass the DbContext to the repository class.

Here's a uml sequence diagram for the whole process:

[image]

Comment: Is The `BackgroundService` and Web App using the same `DbContext` ?

Comment: Your service will be executed once at startup and never again. You need to wrap it in a while loop with a `PeriodTimer` (.NET 6+)

Comment: `PeriodicTimer`* whoops

Comment: @DenisMicheal yes